# What is the difference between the span of a set to its subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

I am confused with some of the definitions of linear algebra. I know that the span of set S is basically the set of all the linear combinations of the vectors in S.

The subspace of the set S is the set of all the vectors in S that are closed under addition and multiplication (and the zero vector).

So my question is, what is the difference between the span of S to the subspace of S?
it seems as if you could find its span in its subspace and its subspace in its span.

Comment: At least as you've written it the notion of "the subspace of a set" doesn't make sense. "Closed under addition" isn't a property of a single vector, but of a collection of vectors. If you just mean the smallest subspace containing $S$, then yes that is the span.

Comment: The span of a set in the smallest subspace containing the set. So, the span of a subspace is the subspace itself.

Answer (score 6):

Take a nonempty subset $S$ of some vector space $V$. Then $\operatorname{span} S$ can be defined in two ways:

- $\operatorname{span} S$ is the set of all linear combinations of vectors in $S$.
- $\operatorname{span} S$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains all the elements of $S$. (How do you construct $\operatorname{span} S$? Take the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain all the element of $S$.)

It turns out that these definitions are equivalent, so if you take one as the definition of $\operatorname{span} S$, then you can prove the other bullet point above as a theorem. See, for instance, Section 2.2 of Hoffman and Kunze's book *Linear Algebra*, second edition.

Answer (score 1):

A subspace $s$ of $S$ is a space within $S$. We have $4$ main subspaces, for instance. The most famous one is the linear combination of columns. For example, if we have $[C_1]$ and $[C_2]$ as columns of a matrix, we define column subspace as $a C_1 + b C_2$.

Any other subspace is just using the very simple idea of above. You can predict how the row space would be.

Now about span, the $a C_1 + b C_2$ is called the span of $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: Use LaTeX please: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I've already edited your answer to make it more readable. Next time, I suggest you try using MathJax.